# Unknown Layer error while loading a keras model having custom Attention layer in it

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have a keras trained model that has custom attention layer in it. I first tried to save by checkpoint while training.  Then while loading I got some unknown layer error. Next I tried to save the model in jason format and weights in h5 file. Next while trying to load the model it shows same and the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/khaledkucse/Project/python/DeepMethodSequenceReccomender/__main__.py", line 48, in <module>
    loaded_model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json,custom_objects={"AttentionLayer":AttentionMechanism.AttentionL})
  File "/home/khaledkucse/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/saving.py", line 368, in model_from_json
    return deserialize(config, custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "/home/khaledkucse/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/layers/__init__.py", line 60, in deserialize
    printable_module_name='layer')
  File "/home/khaledkucse/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/utils/generic_utils.py", line 145, in deserialize_keras_object
    list(custom_objects.items())))
  File "/home/khaledkucse/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/network.py", line 1017, in from_config
    process_layer(layer_data)
  File "/home/khaledkucse/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/network.py", line 1003, in process_layer
    custom_objects=custom_objects)
  File "/home/khaledkucse/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/layers/__init__.py", line 60, in deserialize
    printable_module_name='layer')
  File "/home/khaledkucse/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/utils/generic_utils.py", line 138, in deserialize_keras_object
    ': ' + class_name)
ValueError: Unknown layer: AttentionL
```

I used Custom object parameter in model_from_json function. here is the Code:

```
json_file = open(config.model_file_JSON_path, 'r')
loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
json_file.close()
loaded_model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json,custom_objects={"AttentionLayer":AttentionMechanism.AttentionL})
loaded_model.load_weights(config.model_file_path)
```

I have the get_config() method in my custom layer. Here it is:

```
   def get_config(self):
    config={'step_dim':self.step_dim}
    base_config = super(AttentionL, self).get_config()
    return dict(list(base_config.items()) + list(config.items()))
```

Still now no luck. How can i load my model. Please note, I can save and load my weights only but it creates uninitialised error for Bi-directional LSTM while predicting for test cases.

Comment: The traceback doesn't contain the error message, please also include it verbatim.